# Adding audit columns to a Fluent NHibernate many-to-many junction table

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many, audit

I'm using Fluent NHibernate to generate a database schema from .Net entity classes. I have two classes `User` and `Permission` with a many to many relationship, and Fluent NHibernate is correctly generating a junction table `UsersToPermissions` in the database.

As expected the junction table is storing the primary keys `UserId` and `PermissionId`. What I am wanting is to also have auditing information attached to this table such as `CreatedDate` and `UpdatedDate`. I have already implemented this on the non junction tables using interceptors as described in the [NHibernate documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#events).

How can I implement audit columns on the `UsersToPermissions` table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible directly, because relationships don't have properties.

The easiest way is to map the junction table as an entity, and project the sides using LINQ-to-objects for ease of use.

For example, assuming we call the intermediate entity `UserPermission`:

```
class User
{
    // Real relationship, mapped as bag or set with one-to-many UserPermission
    protected virtual ICollection<UserPermission> UserPermissions { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Permission> Permissions
    {
        get { return from up in UserPermissions select up.Permission; }
    }

    public void Add(Permission permission)
    {
        UserPermissions.Add(new UserPermission
                            {
                                User = this,
                                Permission = permission
                            });
    }
}
```

Permission can have exactly the same if needed.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how projecting the sides using LINQ-to-objects would be done?